# How can I, as a noob to advanced text editing, write a script to automate converion from one enum to another?

Tags: macros, text-editors, visual-studio-code, text-editing, c++

The title is pretty poor, sorry about that. I am using two assembler/disassembler libraries and both have separate register enums. The libraries are Zydis and Capstone. In capstone the register enum is X86_REG_X and in zydis it's ZYDIS_REGISTER_X. It would be easy enough to modify the library by copy pasting the capstone enum into the zydis one and find and replace 'X86_REG' with 'ZYDIS_REGISTER', but I do not want to modify the libraries, instead I want to create a constexpr map that maps zydis registers to capstone registers. This involves a tremendous amount of code duplication. I want to be able to type "RAX" and have a text editor (I use vscode) generate "{ ZYDIS_REGISTER_RAX, X86_REG_RAX },\n" and the be able to type "RBX" and have the text editor make "{ ZYDIS_REGISTER_RBX, X86_REG_RBX },\n" etc. so I just have to type the register names. I could easily make a C program that does this but I want to do it in a convenient, scripting fashion integrated into a text editor (preferable vscode.)

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 11, if i need vi or whatever I can download it

Comment: would snippets work for you? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Answer (score 1):

For what you are describing, I would use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).  AutoHotKey is a very powerful scripting tool that lets you automate a lot of things, like text replacement.  The advantage of AHK over a single application's macros, is that it can be used in *any* application.

I use AHK constantly to do text replacements for my job.  Things like replying to emails, running shell commands, and using text replacement in scripts.  I use it in browsers, terminals, text editors, Slack, email, etc.